# How to display part of an HTML document in Java

Tags: java, html, swing

I have an application where I need to show one specific section of a HTML document within a swing JPanel. The section to be shown depends on what the user is doing at any given time.

I know that JEditorPane can display simple HTML, and in fact in terms of HTML support this is more than enough for my needs. However I don't think I can use this to display only part of the original HTML file.

I thought of putting each section within a div, then hiding all divs with CSS (display: none), and showing only the target section by setting display: block on the section I wanted to show. Unfortunately JEditorPane has limited CSS support and this does not seem to include the "display" attribute.

Before I go and implement something more elaborate, is there any simple way to achieve this goal?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find a way to do what I wanted relying on the CSS support from the `JEditorPane`. What I ended up doing is manually parsing the HTML document and splitting it in "fragments" (top-level DIVs representing sections), then displaying each section as required via `JEditorPane.setText`.

Answer (score 2):

You may try Cobra :

http://lobobrowser.org/cobra.jsp

Comment: Good suggestion, thanks. Although first I'd like to see if there are any options not involving an external library.

Comment: even more recommended dj project: http://djproject.sourceforge.net/main/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Override the ViewFactory and replace DIV views. If they should be hidden let them return 0 from getXXXSpan methods.

See for example the section folding related code http://java-sl.com/collapse_area.html

Comment: That's a very interesting approach. Can you elaborate a bit further?